# No support for locale: en_US.utf8

Tags: linux, locale, initramfs

I am on Linux Mint 17.3. I saw this in the syslog.

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.3) ...
Apr  9 12:01:47 vb-nb-mint updates: update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-32-generic
Apr  9 12:01:51 vb-nb-mint updates: Warning: No support for locale: en_US.utf8
```

I have just noticed this warning? Shouldn't it be en_US.UTF8? Just an idea, otherwise I don't know what this is about.

```
locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: i'm on Arch and mine says it like `LANG=en_US.UTF8`, but  glibc will normalize both and should be ok. in BSD, you'll want UTF-8. stick with dash as it matters when you ssh into other machines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at `/usr/lib/locale/`. If your output looks like this, read on:

```
ls /usr/lib/locale/
C.UTF-8  locale-archive
```

The warning isn't critical, as far as I can tell, but you may try:

```
sudo locale-gen --purge --no-archive
```

This command deletes the archive file and replaces it with the `.utf8` files.

Afterwards you may look at `/usr/lib/locale/` again, it should look somewhat similat to this:

```
ls /usr/lib/locale/
C.UTF-8     de_LI.utf8  en_CA.utf8  en_IN       en_US.utf8
de_AT.utf8  de_LU.utf8  en_DK.utf8  en_NG       en_ZA.utf8
de_BE.utf8  en_AG       en_GB.utf8  en_NZ.utf8  en_ZM
de_CH.utf8  en_AU.utf8  en_HK.utf8  en_PH.utf8  en_ZW.utf8
de_DE.utf8  en_BW.utf8  en_IE.utf8  en_SG.utf8
```

Answer (score 1):

The locale-gen script on Mint 19.3 has the option '--keep-existing' only, at least on my upgrades from 17.1 forward to-date.

Any new locale edited in /etc/locale-gen is not written to /usr/lib/locale.
but to /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive.

In order to work around this and create the directory and associated required locale(s), as user root type:

cd /usr/lib/locale

localedef -f UTF-8 -i en_US ./en_US.utf8

(note the '/', required to create the underlying directory)

Will produce these correctly:

ls /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/

LC_ADDRESS  LC_IDENTIFICATION  LC_MONETARY  LC_PAPER
LC_COLLATE  LC_MEASUREMENT     LC_NAME      LC_TELEPHONE
LC_CTYPE    LC_MESSAGES        LC_NUMERIC   LC_TIME

Why does this happen in the first place?
Because the script /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/root_locale
(called amongst others but normally by update-initramfs) shows the following:

```sh
[ -z "$ROOT_LOCALE" ] && ROOT_LOCALE=`echo $LANG | sed -e 's/UTF/utf/' -e 's/utf-8/utf8/'`
```

Please note this may not be true for future releases of Mint (nor a fresh install or any other distributions and may be overwritten by any update or upgrade).

If you (or other users) use more than one or different language(s) frequently, you could add them to your/their home directories.

As it is a warning, you can also safely ignore it!
e.d.

Using 'dpkg-reconfigure locales' does not produce the required result either, I tested on my upgraded Mint 19.3.(From the command line it looks like it calls locale-gen)